# yii2 urlManager enablePrettyUrl not working

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, yii-url-manager

In Yii2, I cannot enable pretty url's.

My config:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

My script:

```
echo 'enablePrettyUrl: ';
echo Yii::$app->urlManager->enablePrettyUrl ? 'true ' : 'false';

echo '<br>';
echo 'enableStrictParsing: ';
echo Yii::$app->urlManager->enableStrictParsing ? 'true ' : 'false';

echo '<br>';
echo 'showScriptName: ';
echo Yii::$app->urlManager->showScriptName ? 'true ' : 'false';

echo Url::to(['/book/read', 't' => 'booktitle', 'c'=>'chaptertitle']);
```

The output from the script:

```
enablePrettyUrl: true
enableStrictParsing: false
showScriptName: false

/book/read?t=booktitle&c=chaptertitle
```

Clearly, I am not getting pretty Url's. **Why not?**

- We know `enablePrettyUrl=== true`
- I do not believe there is anything wrong with my .htaccess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting pretty URLs. This is a pretty url

```
/book/read?t=booktitle&c=chaptertitle
```

An ugly URL is

```
index.php?r=book/read&t=booktitle&c=chaptertitle
```

So everything works as expected in yii2. Now you may want to make them prettier still, in this case you can add to your rule section something like

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'book/read/<t>/<c>' => 'book/read',
    ]
```

This would generate a link that will look like

```
book/read/booktitle/chaptertitle
```

Change it to suit your needs. No need to change anything in the controller, it will still receive the t and c parameters.

Comment: Oh Thanks. So, this is just a misunderstanding about pretty url's! Indeed, I was looking for `/book/read/booktitle/chaptertitle`. Did this change between Yii 1.1 and Yii 2?

Comment: Not really, I believe they work in the same way. You still need to define URL rules for both of them from what I remember.

Answer (score 1):

you are already getting pretty URL

```
/book/read?t=booktitle&c=chaptertitle
```

is a pretty url. you can also hit it like this

```
/book/read/t/booktitle/c/chaptertitle
```

if you want in browser it will result in same, if you are confusing yourself with `?` in URL.

Comment: How can you hit it like that? It worked like that in Yii 1 (urlFormat=path), whereas I don't think it works like that in yii 2 alone